# How to read from MySQL table Polygon data

Tags: mysql, gps, polygon

I am developing an application that I need location data to be stored on MySQL table. In addition to point locations, I need regions (polygon) as well.

I am currently writing the polygon coordinates as follow :

```
 oMySQLConnecion = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString);
            if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed || oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                oMySQLConnecion.Open();

            }
            if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {                    
                string Query = @"INSERT INTO region (REGION_POLYGON) VALUES (PolygonFromText(@Parameter1))";

                MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, oMySQLConnecion);
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", PolygonString);

                int sqlSuccess = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                oMySQLConnecion.Close();

                oDBStatus.Type = DBDataStatusType.SUCCESS;
                oDBStatus.Message = DBMessageType.SUCCESSFULLY_DATA_UPDATED;
                return oDBStatus;
            }
```

After the execution, I see the Blob in MySQL table.

[image]

Now I want to read the data back for my testing and it does not work the way I tried below :

```
 if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string Query = @"SELECT REGION_ID,REGION_NICK_NAME,GeomFromText(REGION_POLYGON) AS POLYGON FROM region WHERE REGION_USER_ID = @Parameter1";

                MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, oMySQLConnecion);
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", UserID);

                using (var reader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        R_PolygonCordinates oRec = new R_PolygonCordinates();
                        oRec.RegionNumber = Convert.ToInt32(reader["REGION_ID"]);
                        oRec.RegionNickName = reader["REGION_NICK_NAME"].ToString();
                        oRec.PolygonCodinates = reader["POLYGON"].ToString();
                        polygons.Add(oRec);
                    }
                }
                int sqlSuccess = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                oMySQLConnecion.Close();
                return polygons;
            }
```

It returns an empty string.

1. I am not sure if I am really writing the data since I can not read Blob.
2. Is my reading syntax incorrect?

** Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2017. The MySQL latest version with Spacial classes.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to `SELECT GeomFromText()` -- I suspect you want the opposite, `AsWKT()` or `ST_AsWKT()`.

Comment: Excellent... It's working (used AsWKT())...! Whats the difference between AsWKT() and ST_AsWKT() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GeomFromText()` takes a WKT (the standardized "well-known text" format) value as input and returns the MySQL internal geometry type as output.

This is the inverse of what you need, which is `ST_AsWKT()` or `ST_AsText()` -- take an internal-format geometry object as input and return WKT as output.

Prior to 5.6, the function is called `AsWKT()` or `AsText()`.  In 5.7 these are all synonyms for exactly the same function, but the non `ST_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in the future.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext

I don't know for certain what the `ST_` prefix means, but I assume it's "spatial type."  There's some discussion in [WL#8055](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8055) that may be of interest.